# What is the difference between fixation and preservation?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, biology

I'm currently doing some translations and I found one phrase that is being specially difficult:

"After being fixed with formalin, the specimens were preserved in ethyl alcohol."

Even after running some research, I can't still tell the difference between **fixed** (in biology context) and **preserved**. Could someone please help me with that?

Comment: [Fixation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixation_(histology)) is a specific process used to prepare samples for microscopy, etc. You'd probably be better off asking on a biology forum for precise details. Or reading Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

from my understanding:
Fixation = usually the solution is toxic and your specimen shouldn’t be stored in it for an extended period of time, otherwise your specimen might degrade. Fixation is a time-sensitive thing.

Preservation = the solution isn’t toxic and therefore your specimen can be stored in this solution for an extended period of time without degradation.

Please visit this page for more information. I was looking for a good website that had a clear differentiation between the two: [The article was written by Joel W. Martin from the Natural History Museum of LA County](http://clade.ansp.org/malacology/people/rosenberg/archiving/method/fixation_preservation.html)